# Is using imgur to host pictures considered reliable?

Tags: discussion, images

So I am a huge fan of tikz (still a bit of a noob to be honest). I find that adding graphics can be helpful for a lot of problems, but I am wondering if hosting pictures in imgur is a good idea, as they could potentially dissapear. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Related (but old) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com

Comment: Having images hosted by imgur through a dedicated arrangement with StackExchange/Stackoverflow is intended to solve (or at least mitigate) problems of online impermanence.

Comment: @hardmath do you know any details of the arrangement?

Comment: See [this Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251937/155839) and its link on Meta StackExchange.  My takeaway is that the possibility of image linkrot was addressed early in the design of Stackoverflow.  The chosen solution has proved reliable in a decade of use.  Of course technology marches on, so image formats can evolve, but that can be addressed at the repository level.

Comment: If there's time and all that, then TiKz ha! this way you'd gain more and more experience on learning about it.

Comment: @Verónica yeah tikz is awesome, but I don't think you can render it with mathjax, so the current method is to convert it into a picture and upload the picture.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. Since MathJax is pretty much like LaTeX.. You could request tho.

Comment: A related post on this meta: [Permanent Picture Uploads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4205).

Answer (score 4):

While editing a post, there is a button at the top of the editing pane:

[image]

This button can be used to add images to a post.  When you click on that button, it opens up a dialog which asks you to provide the URL of an image, or to upload an image.  If you upload an image, it will be uploaded to imgur, then embedded here.  As Math SE incorporates imgur uploading right into its interface, you are fine to use it for hosting images—there is good reason to believe that the images will persist at least as long as the SE network exists.

Indeed, SE has a [deal with imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com) to provide hosting services.  More details can be found on [the Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/?_ga=2.54232813.432739139.1617630370-712356490.1585422292).  Note that both of these links are about a decade old, but nothing significant has changed in the meantime.

Comment: why do you think I am safe?

Comment: @Jorge: If my memory serves me right, SE has a deal with imgur so that the images don't disappear after some time. Other than that, what kind of safety issues are you concerned with?

Comment: I don't really care about safety ( which I should but I don't). But "don't dissapear after some time" isn't very reassuring to be completely honest.

Comment: @Jorge Almost surely the images will not disappear before SE does, since that would make many SE answers unintelligible. Any my memory agrees with Asaf's regarding the deal between SE and imgur.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wasn't there some issue awhile ago where imgur was repurposing very old links to show ads, or was that some other service?

Comment: @Matt: No, that was a different service.

Comment: @MattSamuel A related post on this meta: [Please don't flag posts containing re-purposed ImageShack image URLs as spam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21231). You can find also some related discussions on [meta.se]: [Ban ImageShack images because they are reusing old URLs for advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771).